# How can I embed a document viewer in a web page and can customize viewer Ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, document

In my Web application (document management system) i am trying to add a document viewer what is view almost all type document like .pdf, .doc, .docx, .txt, .csvx etc,

Must have to customize view functionality (show or hide - Download button, print button, zoom in out, showing or hiding number of page etc) for different role user.

Is there any good plugin or library that can fulfill my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i've not enough reputation to only comment your post.

I don't know about any plugin that fulfill your requirements, but for some of your files, that can be natively displayed by a browser, you can easily use iframes to display them. With a little bit of JavaScript, you can make a print button with css displaying your iframe at 100% width/height of your document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

Zoom in or out is easy with css transform scale. 
Download can be done with a link and appropriate headers on server side.

For proprietary docs like .docx or .xls, Trying to parse and display from scratch such files can be a real pain. If i were you, i would try to find a pdf converter for all formats that you have to support and use pdf to display a view. For the download, you just have to link the real file.

Hope it will help.